# How submit Angular form with Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

Do you know how can I submit my form using HttpInterceptor? My GET method it is ok using interceptor getting token and bringing the result etc... but when I try to submit my form nothing happen, the back-end is not being called.

TokenInterceptor.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private kcService: KeycloakService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    return from(this.kcService.init())
      .pipe(switchMap(authToken => {
        debugger;
        if(authToken){
          const headers = request.headers
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken)
            .append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          console.log(authToken);
          const reqClone = request.clone({
            headers
          });
          return next.handle(reqClone);
        }
      }));
  }

}
```

ItemService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

    itensUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/itens'

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private kcService: KeycloakService) { }

    list(){
     return this.http.get<any[]>(this.itensUrl);
    }

    addiction(item: any){
      return this.http.post(this.itensUrl, item);
    }
  }
```

app.modules.ts:

```
 providers: [
    ItemService,
    KeycloakService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
```

ItemPatrimonyComponent.ts

```
export class ItemPatrimonyComponent implements OnInit {

  itens = [];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listAll();
  }

  listAll(){
    this.itemService.list().subscribe(data => this.itens = data)
    console.log(this.itens);
  }

  add(frm:FormControl){
    this.itemService.addiction(frm.value)
      .subscribe(() => {
        frm.reset();
        this.listAll();
       });
  }
```

Comment: Sure, you have a `if` condition but no `else`. try providing one or providing a token.

Comment: thanks man but the problem is: looks my interceptor is intercepting GET but not POST, when I try to submit is not calling the back-end. I removed the if condition.

Comment: The interceptor intercepts **every** request. If your requests go into your interceptor, they will enter the process, don't satisfy the condition, and break the stream flow. you have to return `next.handle` for **every** request, and you don't, that's why you don't see your requests being made.

Comment: thanks again pal. Sorry but you mean: I need to change my intercept method ? I'm already returning "return next.handle(reqClone);"

Comment: You're only returning it in the `if` statement. What do you return when you don't have an `authToken` ? Where is the return statement ? I don't tell you to change your interceptor, I'm telling you to at least return something in all cases.

Comment: ahh ok. But anyway I removed the if condition. Debugging I can see my interceptor being called just when the application start.

Comment: Probably because you make an HTTP request ?

Comment: yes I do that's why, but for another HTTP request "POST" it is not being called. tha's my html code to submit:

Comment: <form #frm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="add(frm)">

Comment: <div class="ui-g-12">
      <button pButton type="submit" label="Submit"
      [disabled]="frm.invalid"></button>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on Keycloak init function, and you could not debug your problem because on your interceptor you are adding the debugger inside the callback of init instead of outside it.
If init is called and refresh the page (what keycloak does) you will never see the callback debugger working, what you need to do is on your keycloak service instead of call directly init verify if the token is already defined if it returns the token instead of call keycloak.init on each request.
Something like:

```
if (this.keycloak.token) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.keycloak.token);
}
return this.keycloak.init().then(()=> this.keycloak.token)
```